# How to delete a record from Oracle Table in Python SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, oracle, sqlalchemy

Passing a delete statement does not delete record from a table. The code executes successfully without errors/warnings but the record does not get deleted.

I tried running the following code to delete a row using sqlalchemy engine (OracleDB)

```
sql = "DELETE FROM table WHERE id=1"

engine.connect().execute(text(sql))
```

Logs:

[image]

Comment: An incorrect table name specification *would* cause an error to be thrown. If no errors returned, then the most likely explanation is that the transaction was *not* committed and therefore the deletion was not made permanent. Did you explicitly commit the transaction?

Comment: @pmdba I added execution_options(autocommit=True) to the connection, but the record is still there

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to add `autocommit`:

```
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

engine = create_engine("oracle+cx_oracle://user:password@hostname:1521/?servic_eanme=ServiceName", echo=True)
conn = engine.connect()
conn = conn.execution_options(autocommit=True)

query = "DELETE FROM temp_student WHERE id={id}"
conn.execute(query.format(id=2))
```

Comment: Hey. I added the autocommit line, but it is not deleting the record.

Comment: @hootowl, Could you please check the `data type` of the `id` column you are using, are they same or not

Comment: It is a number.

Comment: Whether you able to fetch records for that table. 

`query = "SELECT * FROM temp_student WHERE id = 2"`

`records = conn.execute(query)`

`print(records.fetchall())`

Comment: And also in the `create_engine` add another argument `echo=True`.This will give you the detail log. You can try executing the delete statement directly in the database.

Comment: I am able to fetch records. Added the echo in the create engine. Attached the screenshot in the post.

Comment: Were you able to delete the records directly from the oracle database as well

Comment: Nope, delete is not happening

Comment: Then you have insufficient privileges or the database/table is in readonly mode. Try something like - `ALTER DATABASE database_name SET READ_WRITE WITH NO_WAIT`.

Comment: Sorry, I misread your comment. I am able to delete directly from the table. Delete is not happening in the python script.

Comment: Try using format:

`query = "DELETE FROM table_name WHERE id = {id}"`
`conn.execute(query.format(id=2)).` Or can try using bind variables as well.